# How to write a Jest configuration file

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to pass along a configuration file to Jest in order to run tests only from a given directory.

According to documentation, you can use `config.testPathDirs`: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-testpathdirs-array-string and you can call `jest --config=<config-file>`.

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't include any description of how the configuration file should look like.

I tried both these options in a `jest-config.js` file:

```
testPathDirs = ['coredata/src'];
```

and

```
config.testPathDirs(['coredata/src']);
```

and ran:

```
$ jest --config=jest-config.js
```

...but I get this type of error:

```
$ jest --config=jest-config.js
Using Jest CLI v0.4.0
Failed with unexpected error.

/Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/src/jest.js:179
      throw error;
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:291:23
    at _fulfilled (/Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/carles/dev/azazo/coredata/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I figured out that the config file is JSON.

```
{
  "testPathDirs": ["coredata/src"]
}
```

Unfortunately I found nowhere in the documentation a hint about this.

Comment: in your package.json:   
"jest": {
    "testPathDirs": ["app/"]
  },

Comment: The documentation can be found here https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html

Comment: Ah thanks @hakunin that may have been a recent addition (more recent than my question for sure) https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#configuration

Comment: Right now "testsPathDirs" was changed to "roots" as stated here:
[jest roots config](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#roots-array-string)

Comment: I do not agree with the answer here. I have posted my own, in hopes to further clarify how simple it is as of August 2017. It does not require that your config file be in json format.

Comment: Well take into account that this answer is >2 years old, in a fast moving world :)

Comment: This has been Deprecated with `roots` and `rootDir`

Answer (score 16):

Seems to me you can configure jest directly within your `package.json`, see https://github.com/shidhincr/react-jest-gulp-jspm-seed/blob/master/package.json.

```
{
  "name": "react-jest-gulp-seed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Seed for React Jest Gulp Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "jspm install"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "./preprocessor.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/jspm_packages"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "./node_modules/react"
    ]
  },
  "author": "Shidhin CR <shidhincr@gmail.com> (http://www.undefinednull.com/)",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.4.1",
    "harmonize": "^1.4.1",
    "jest-cli": "^0.4.1",
    "jspm": "^0.15.5",
    "react": "^0.13.2",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.7.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {},
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "npm:react@^0.13.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.1.13",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.1.13",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^0.9.4"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do i put in the package.json file under `jest` if I want to use a separate config file for configuring jest?

Comment: @Panshul, When you call `jest` in the test script, you pass in the path to the config file like `jest --config ./config/jest-config.js`

Comment: The question is about configuration file not `package.json`. Answer is not valid

Answer (score 11):

As of the current date of October 5, 2018, I was able to setup a jest configuration file with ease, without it requiring it to be in JSON format.

My package.json scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest-config.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "postinstall": "webpack"
  }
```

I decided to keep the jest-config file in the root path alongside package.json, so that's where it is pointing to, but you can put it anywhere you want. Here is the configuration file, albeit a little short:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "./enzyme.js",
  roots: [
    "../__tests__"
  ],
  modulePaths: [
    "./__stubs__"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ".scss$": "scss-stub.js"
  }
}
```

The Jest documentation in the "Configuring Jest" section ([link here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html)) says that you can create it with a module.exports object. They include a caveat that says, "Please keep in mind that the resulting configuration must be JSON-serializable", which adds to the confusion. "Delightful Javascript Testing!" Hah!

**P.S.** The roots property in the config tells Jest where to look for all of your tests. Thought it might help.

Comment: what if the config file is typescript

Answer (score 8):

The docs were updated to explain the configuration. Here is the link for anyone looking for more information:

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#content

**The gist:**

If using the `--config <path/to/json>` to direct jest to your configuration json file, you only put the JSON information in the file without the "jest" keyword.

```
// config.json at <path/to/json>
{
   "verbose": true
}
```

If you want to use the package.json to configure jest, add the "jest" key and then your configuration.

```
// package.json 
{ 
   "name": "packageName",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "jest": {
     "verbose": true
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Valerie -- unfortunately this link is 404ing, though.

Comment: Current link (as of Oct 2017) is https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#content

Answer (score 7):

**For JEST V20+:**

```
{
 "roots": ["__tests__/"]
}
```

For v 20-, you will get following warning if you use testPathDirs:

Deprecation Warning:

> Option "testPathDirs" was replaced by "roots".
>
> Jest now treats your current configuration as:    {
>        "roots": ["**tests**/unit/"]    }
>
> Please update your configuration.

Answer (score 4):

```
// package.json

{
 ...
 scripts: {
   "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js"
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Ref. https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Comment: @ikhvjs where is it? I don't see where it is

Comment: @Ooker first sentence. It is recommended to define the configuration in a dedicated JavaScript, TypeScript or JSON file. The file will be discovered automatically, if it is named jest.config.js|ts|mjs|cjs|json. You can use --config flag to pass an explicit path to the file.