# How to start an express server using testEnvironment as NodeEnvironment?

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

After looking into the questions:

1. [Async setup of environment with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508847/async-setup-of-environment-with-jest)
2. [window/document not defined in import](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/issues/234)
3. [Configure Jest global tests setup with .ts file (TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318230/configure-jest-global-tests-setup-with-ts-file-typescript)
4. [About app.listen() callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222074/about-app-listen-callback)
5. [How to write a Jest configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027494/how-to-write-a-jest-configuration-file)
6. [NodeJS: How to get the server's port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840879/nodejs-how-to-get-the-servers-port)
7. https://alligator.io/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-express/
8. [Promisify server.listen](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21482)
9. [Unexpected token import in custom node environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930302/unexpected-token-import-in-custom-node-environment)
10. [How to access class properties of Jest Test Environment inside child test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545232/how-to-access-class-properties-of-jest-test-environment-inside-child-test)
11. [Cannot create custom TestEnvironment in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359158/cannot-create-custom-testenvironment-in-jest)
12. [globalSetup is executed in different context than tests](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6007)
13. [global beforeAll](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3832)
14. [How to test url change with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977862/how-to-test-url-change-with-jest)
15. [Specify window.location for each test file for Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975981/specify-window-location-for-each-test-file-for-jest)
16. [window.location.href can't be changed in tests](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890)
17. [global beforeAll](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3832)
18. [How do I test a single file using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725955/how-do-i-test-a-single-file-using-jest)
19. https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/jest

I was able to do this:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "./testEnvironment.js",
  }
}
```

**testEnvironment.js**

```javascript
const express = require('express');
// const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node'); // for server node apps
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-jsdom'); // for browser js apps

class ExpressEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    const app = express();

    this.global.server = app.listen(0, "127.0.0.1", () => {
        console.log(`Running express server on '${JSON.stringify(server.address())}'...`);

        how to make setup() wait until app.listen callback is finished, 
        i.e., the server has properly started.

    });
    app.use(express.static('../testfiles'));
  }

  async teardown() {
    this.global.server.close();
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}

module.exports = ExpressEnvironment;
```

How to make `setup()` wait until `app.listen()` callback is finished, i.e., the server has properly started?

Before, when I was using `beforeAll()`, my code was working fine because I could use the `done()` async callback passed by `beforeAll()`:

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var server;

beforeAll(async (done) => {
    server = app.listen(0, "127.0.0.1", () => {
        console.log(`Running express server on '${JSON.stringify(server.address())}'...`);
        done();
    });
    app.use(express.static('../testfiles'));
});

afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
});
```

How would be the equivalent to the beforeAll `done()` callback on the NodeEnvironment `setup()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by awaiting the listen even, wrapping it in a promise, and calling the promise resolve as the callback to the server listen

```js
  const app = express();
  let server;
  await new Promise(resolve => server = app.listen(0, "127.0.0.1", resolve));
  this.global.server = server;
```

You could also put a custom callback that will just call the promise resolver as the third argument to the `app.listen()` and it should run that code then call resolve if you need some sort of diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Robert Mennell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5377773) answer:

> You could also put a custom callback that will just call the promise resolver as the third argument to the `app.listen()` and it should run that code then call resolve if you need some sort of diagnostics.

```js
let server;
const app = express();

await new Promise(function(resolve) {
    server = app.listen(0, "127.0.0.1", function() {
        console.log(`Running express server on '${JSON.stringify(server.address())}'...`);
        resolve();
    });
});
this.global.server = server;
```

Then, you can access the `this.global.server` in your tests files to get the server port/address: [Is it possible to create an Express.js server in my Jest test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260044/4934640)